# Conjecture for a closed form of a parametric integral

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, stirling-numbers

Let us assume that $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is quite easy to prove that:

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \log (1-x) \, {\rm d}x = - \frac{\mathcal{H}_n}{n}$$

since if we use the series representation of $\mathcal{H}_m$ we have that:

\begin{equation} \mathcal{H}_m = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{m+k} \right ] \tag{1}\end{equation}

and it follows that our initial integral , call that $\mathcal{J}$ ,

\begin{align*} \mathcal{J} &=\int_{0}^{1} x^m \log(1-x) \, {\rm d}x \\   &= - \int_{0}^{1}x^m \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \, {\rm d}x \\   &= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{1}x^{m+n} \, {\rm d}x\\   &= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \left ( n+m+1 \right )}\\   &= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{(m+1)n} - \frac{1}{(m+1) \left ( m+n+1 \right )} \right]\\   &= - \frac{1}{m+1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+m+1} \right ]\\  &\overset{(1)}{=} - \frac{\mathcal{H}_{m+1}}{m+1} \end{align*}

Now let us raise the exponent of $\log (1-x)$ by one. That is we now consider the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \log^2 (1-x) \, {\rm d}x = \frac{1}{n} \left [ \mathcal{H}_n^2 + \mathcal{H}_n^{(2)} \right ]$$

The derivation is pretty much easy. What can we say for the integral

$$\mathcal{J}(n, m) =\int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \log^m (1-x) \, {\rm d}x $$

I have a conjecture that states that it will involve a sum of $\mathcal{H}_n$ raised to the corresponding power of the log and a sum of $\mathcal{H}_n^{(m)}$. However, I am unable to make any progress for the general case. Diffing the Beta won't help us here. This is what I've done for the $m=2$ case. I just diffed the Beta twice. Any clever approach?

Also what we can say for the integral:

$$\mathcal{J}^*(n, m) =\int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \log^m (1+x) \, {\rm d}x $$

Well, one last thing one should note is that both integrals actually connect to [Stirling Numbers of first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html). Maybe we could use the Taylor series expansion of $\log^m (1 \pm x)$ and reduce the problem to Stirling numbers. I am not that familiar though.

Comment: so your notation is $H_n^2 = (H_n)^2$ while $H_n^{(2)}  = \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m^2}$

Comment: Yes.. ! And in general 

$$\mathcal{H}_n^{(m)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^m}$$

Comment: You should recall that $H_n$ is the n-th harmonic number in the first line. Have some mercy for all people (sometimes not bad mathematicians) that do not remember that in this context it is the harmonic numbers (it could have been the Hermite polynomials for example... or even someting. It is essential to give a little recall of the context !

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839100/closed-form-for-an-integral-with-log-and-power

Comment: I feel a complete idiot ... !! I totally forgot that I asked it again ..... Makes me cry from laughters!

Comment: Welp, guess we closing this huh?

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer, only some thoughts**

Let $\displaystyle A_n^m = \int_0^{1} x^n \log^{m}(1-x) dx, \ A_n^0 = \frac{1}{n+1}$.
You get the following recurrence :
$$A_n^m =-\frac{m}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{m-1}$$

but I admit I'm not sure what to do with it. There is the related but different recurrence ${n \choose m} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {k \choose m-1}$ and [the connexion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficients_as_polynomials) $\binom{n}{m} = \sum_{k=0}^m \left[{ m \atop k} \right]\frac{n^k}{m!}$ to the the [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Generating_function), appearing in the Taylor expansion $\frac{\log^m (1+z)}{m!} = \sum_{k=m}^\infty (-1)^{k-m} \left[{k\atop m}\right] \frac{z^k}{k!} $ so that 
$\displaystyle A_n^m = \textstyle \int_0^1 x^n m!\sum_{k=m}^\infty (-1)^{k-m} \left[{k\atop m}\right] \frac{x^k}{k!}dx = \displaystyle \sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{m! (-1)^{k-m}}{k! (n+k+1)} \left[{k\atop m}\right] $

Since $\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m \frac{\log^m(1-x)}{m!} = e^{z \log(1-x)} = (1-x)^z$ we have the nice generating function
$\displaystyle F(z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{A_n^m}{m!} z^m = \textstyle\int_0^1 x^n \sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m \frac{\log^m(1-x)}{m!} dx $ $= \int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^z dx = B(n+1,z+1)$
where $B(x,y)$ is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

---

$\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{m\log^{m-1}(1-x)}{x-1} dx = \log^m(1-\epsilon)$ and this is what we need for integrating by parts

$$A_n^m = \int_0^{1} x^n \log^{m}(1-x) dx$$ 
$\textstyle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{(1-\epsilon)^{n+1}}{n+1}\log^{m}(\epsilon)-\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{\log^{m-1}(1-x)}{x-1} dx $ $=  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{m\log^{m-1}(1-x)}{(n+1)(x-1)} dx-\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{\log^{m-1}(1-x)}{x-1} dx$
$\textstyle = \frac{m}{n+1}\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{x-1}\log^{m-1}(1-x)dx = -\sum_{k=0}^n \int_0^1 x^k\log^{m-1}(1-x)dx$
$$=-\sum_{k=0}^n A_k^{m-1}$$