# How to prove that $ -n \int _0 ^1 x^{n-1} \log(1-x)dx$ equals the $n$-th harmonic number?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

From *(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series* section 1.3:

> $$H_n = -n\int _0 ^1 x^{n-1} \log(1-x)dx$$

The proof of which was appetizingly difficult. I was unable to answer the follow-up challenge question, and do not have access to the given solution. It asks:

> Is it possible to [prove this equality] with high school knowledge only (supposing we know and use the notation of the harmonic numbers)?

I've been fiddling with the integral on the right for an hour, but that $\log$ really throws a wrench in my plans.

Comment: Please avoid writing a title with only a formula, and *really* avoid writing it as big as you have. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles) for more tips about fomulae in titles.

Comment: Approach0 gives [this more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839100/int-01-xn-logm-1-x-rm-dx), I'm not sure if it helps.

Comment: @ heepo: +1 Good question. To my astonishment this simple reformulation by partial integration of the well known relation $H_n=\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx$ is missing in Wolfram and Wikipedia. It should be added there.

Comment: A generalization for real $a$ with $a+n\gt 0$ is $-n \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \log \left(1-x^a\right) \, dx=H_{\frac{n}{a}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call the RHS $I_n$, then
\begin{align}I_n-I_{n-1}&=\int_0^1((n-1)x^{n-2}-nx^{n-1})\log(1-x)\,dx\\
&=\left[(x^{n-1}-x^n)\log(1-x)\right]_{x=0}^1
+\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}-x^n}{1-x}\,dx
\end{align}
on integration by parts.
Then
$$\lim_{x\to1}(x^{n-1}-x^n)\log(1-x)=\lim_{x\to1}(1-x)\log(1-x)=
\lim_{y\to0}y\log y=-\lim_{t\to\infty}te^{-t}=0$$
and the integral reduces to $\int_0^1x^{n-1}\,dx=1/n$. Therefore
$I_n-I_{n-1}=1/n$. Similarly $I_1=1$, using integration by parts.
I'd count all of this as A-level level maths.

Answer (score 6):

My usual naive plug in and assume
everything converges.

$\begin{array}\\
-n\int _0 ^1 x^{n-1} \log(1-x)dx
&=n\int _0 ^1 x^{n-1} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{m}dx\\
&=n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{m}\int _0 ^1 x^{n-1} x^mdx\\
&=n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{m}\int _0 ^1 x^{n+m-1}dx\\
&=n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{m}\dfrac1{n+m}\\
&=n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{m(n+m)}\\
&=n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n}(\dfrac1{m}-\dfrac1{n+m})\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(\dfrac1{m}-\dfrac1{n+m})\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{m}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n+m}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{m}-\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{m}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{m}-\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{m}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\dfrac1{m}\\
&=H_n\\
\end{array}
$

If you do the same thing
with $\log(1+x)$,
you get a similar result
but it cancels out
only for even $n$ -
I got 
$-n\int _0 ^1 x^{n-1} \log(1+x)dx\\
=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}-(-1)^n\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}
$.

In any case,
$-n\int _0 ^1 x^{n-1} \log(1+x)dx
\to \ln(2)
$.

Comment: Very nicely done (+1)

Comment: @ marty cohen +1 Here we go again with $\log(2)$ ;-)

Comment: @ marty cohen I get $-n \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \log (x+1) \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(H_{\frac{n}{2}}-H_{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)-\log (2) \to -\log(2)$. Notice the sign error.

Comment: I'll check into that. And looking at the integral, without the minus sign in front, it has to be positive, so with a minus sign it has to be negative.

Comment: So you should correct the sign error in the last formula of your solution.

Answer (score 4):

$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_0^1 x^{k-1}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k-1}dx\\=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx\overset{IBP}{=}\underbrace{-\ln(1-x)(1-x^n)|_0^1}_{0}-n\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)dx$$

Comment: @ Ali Shather +1 Very elegant two liner.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze thank you for the kind words.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but an extended comment, as the reasoning is probably not suited for high school students, as requested in the OP.

This proof starts with the observation that $\log(1-x) = \frac{d}{da} (1-x)^{a-1} |_{a\to 1}$ with which the integral in question can be written thus

$$-n \int_0^1 \log(1-x) x^{n-1}\,dx=- n\frac{d}{da}\left( \int_0^1 (1-x)^{a-1} x^{n-1}\,dx \right)|_{a\to 1} \\=- \frac{d}{da}\left( B(a,n) \right)|_{a\to 1}=- \frac{d}{da}\left( \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma[n+1]}{\Gamma(a+n)}\right)|_{a\to 1}\\= \left(\frac{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (n+1) \psi ^{(0)}(a+n)}{\Gamma (a+n)}-\frac{\Gamma (a) \psi ^{(0)}(a) \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (a+n)}\right)|_{a\to 1}\\=\psi ^{(0)}(n+1)+\gamma= H_n$$

Remark:  this method is easily adapted to integrals of the type $\int_0^1 \log^k (1-x) x^{n-1}\,dx$.