# On the evaluation of $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}\log(1+x)\,dx$ in terms of the harmonic numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

Is my evaluation of this integral correct? Here is my work.

$$I:=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}\log(1+x)\,dx$$

$I.B.P$

$$I=\frac{1}{n}\log(2)-\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x}\,dx$$

Define:

$$J:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x}\,dx$$

$$J=(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-1+(-x)^n+1}{1+x}\,dx$$

$$J=(-1)^n\log(2)+(-1)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-(-x)^n}{1+x}\,dx$$

$$J=(-1)^n\log(2)+(-1)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-x)^k\,dx$$

$$J=(-1)^n\log(2)+(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{1}x^k\,dx$$

$$J=(-1)^n\log(2)+(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$

$$I=\frac{1}{n}\log(2)-\frac{1}{n}[(-1)^n\log(2)+(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}]$$

$$I=\frac{(1-(-1)^n)\log(2)}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$

And whether my work is correct or not, can this integral be expressed in terms of the harmonic numbers?

Comment: Note that $ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=H_{n}-H_{\lfloor\frac n 2\rfloor} $

Comment: $ \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1+x)d x=\frac{H_{n}-H_{n/2}}{n}$. To prove it, use the integral form of $H_n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that $ -n \int _0 ^1 x^{n-1} \log(1-x)dx$ equals the $n$-th harmonic number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460270/how-to-prove-that-n-int-0-1-xn-1-log1-xdx-equals-the-n-th-harmoni)

Answer (score 0):

Your work seems correct so far, although I do not know how to finish it. Perhaps @Indianimperialist123's comment will help. Here is a method using series expansions.

Expanding the logarithm by its [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm) around $x=1$,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1x^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}x^{k}\ dx&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\int_0^1x^{k+n-1}\ dx \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k(n+k)}
\end{align*}$$
splitting the alternating series into its even and odd parts,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k(n+k)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(2k-1)(n+2k-1)}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2k(n+2k)}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
both series can be evaluated in terms of the Digamma function given the [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula),
$$\psi(x+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{k(x+k)}\right)$$
this yields a closed form,
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2n}\left(\psi\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)+\log(4)\right)$$
and the alternate form (using harmonic numbers) is obtained by the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization),
$$\psi(x+1)=H_{x-1}-\gamma$$
so,
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2n}\left(H_\frac{n-1}{2}-H_\frac{n}{2}+\log(4)\right).$$
Numerical check for $n=11$,
$$\int_0^1x^{10}\log(1+x)\ dx=0.0590682135978\dots \\
\frac{H_{5}-H_{11/2}+\log(4)}{22}=0.0590682135978\dots$$

Comment: That is not the *Taylor* series of the digamma function. Leaving that aside, the question also concerned whether or not the OP's work is correct, which has not been addressed here

Comment: @FShrike. Good point, I will work on fixing that now.